# AFOpenFlow Image Sizes on iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, coverflow

I have an iPad application with an AFOpenFlowView implemented in it. In my nib file, I made the OpenFlowView the width of the ipad (768 pixels) and made it the proper height, however, for some reason my images are showing up with the sides cut off. I'm trying to get the images to fit the width of the screen (they're all 768 width) in portrait mode. I was able to do this on the iPhone version (I made the images with a width of 320) and it worked fine. Any help on getting these images to fit the width of the screen and not get their sides cut off would be much appreciated!

PS I've tried making the openflow width exceed the bounds of the ipad (in the nib file) to see if the sides would show, and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with the values in the `AFOpenFlowConstants.h` file.

These settings worked OK for me but you can tweak them further:

```
    #define COVER_SPACING 80
    #define CENTER_COVER_OFFSET 140
    #define SIDE_COVER_ANGLE .15
    #define SIDE_COVER_ZPOSITION -40
```